# How to enable web browser to open ~/Desktop/htdocs/index.html

Tags: browser, html, htdocs

My web browsers can't open `~/Desktop/htdocs/index.html` (located on the desktop).

I tried right clicking on .html that is outside the htdocs folder (I usually successfully use 'Open with' in my old system.) But this is a new system and one of the browsers in this new system worked well two days ago.

I tried using the data in [Can't create a folder inside my local server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120412/cant-create-a-folder-inside-my-local-server)
There is no folder with the name 'lampp' in opt folder (I don't know whether it is essential to read the content).  The following command didn't work.

```
sudo chown $USER:webuser /opt/lampp/htdocs/
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

The output was:

```
chown: invalid group: ‘myname:webuser’
```

So I couldn't proceed.

The only thing I want is to read the stuff in the htdocs (which is not protected). I have granted permission in the properties in the HTML document (text/html) file to use myself.

Comment: `My web browsers can't open htdoc/index.html` How are you trying to access it? What do you get in your browser? Is your webserver configured? `There is nothing in opt folder` What do you mean by this? What does `opt` has to do with this? How did you install your lampp stack? Where is `hotdoc/index.html` located? Sorry for the pile of questions, but your question is very unclear as it is right now.

Comment: @Dan: I have clarified the possible doubts.

Comment: I edited your question based on what you said. If it is on `~/Desktop` is not on `/opt/lampp/`. For this case you can just `chown $USER:$USER`

Comment: Thank you for your efforts for solving this issue. It was an error while copying the complete files from one system. A few of the files had missed.  When I tried to copy all the files again it worked well. Thanks.